# How could I know if a documentation deals with Apache 2.2 or Apache 2.4? Any "striking" criterion?

Tags: server, apache2

As I'm new to managing Apache, [I found this article](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/apache-module-mod-expires), from which I want to learn how to enable mod_deflate on Apache. I use Apache 2.4 and given I'm no Apache expert, I can't strictly determine if this article talks about version 2.2 or 2.4...

How will you determine this? I am sure there is more than 1 way, but what is the most efficient/fastest way that will always work when asking if a doc deals with 2.2 or 2.4?

Comment: Check the documentation for the modules and directives mentioned in the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the article mentions it, you can't verify it accuratly. You're best bet is to check [Apache's official documenation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) and verify the content of the article matches what you see in the docs.

The Apache docs may seem complex at first if you aren't used to them, but you'll get the hangs of them after a short while.

Having said that, there aren't a lot of differences between 2.2 and 2.4. And while looking at the upgrade guide from 2.2 to 2.4: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html, at first glance, there doesn't seem to be anything related to the mod_expires module. So in theory, that article you found should be valid for both versions.